# how to write a correct search function in C?

Tags: c, search

i have a problem in 'search' function, keep showing 'record not found' i have successfully save it into file and i can display it. can someone tell me in which part i wrote it wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMYQX.png)

```
typedef struct vaccine{
    char vacname[20]; 
    char code[5];
    char country[20];
    int dosage, quantity;   
    float population;
}vaccine;

void addVaccine(){
    vaccine *v;
    FILE *fp;
    int n, i;
    printf("Enter how many vaccine you want: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    v= (vaccine*)calloc(n, sizeof(vaccine));
    fp = fopen("vaccine.txt","w");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Enter Vaccine Name: ");
        scanf("%s", v[i].vacname);
        printf("Enter Code: ");
        scanf("%s", v[i].code);
        printf("Enter Country: ");
        scanf("%s", v[i].country);
        printf("Enter Dosage: ");
        scanf("%d", &v[i].dosage);
        printf("Enter Quantity: ");
        scanf("%d", &v[i].quantity);
        printf("Enter Population: ");
        scanf("%.2f", &v[i].population);    

        fwrite(&v[i],sizeof(vaccine),1,fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

here is my search function which i have problem with;

```
void search(){
    vaccine v;
    FILE *fp;
    int i, code, found=0;
    fp = fopen("vaccine.txt","r");

    printf("Enter code to search: ");
    scanf("%s", &code);

    while(fread(&v,sizeof(vaccine),1,fp))
    { 
        if(v.code == code){
        found=1;
        printf("\n%s\t%s\t%d",
        v.vacname,v.code,v.quantity);
        }
    }
    if(!found)
    printf("\nRecord Not Found");
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: It appears that you are comparing a char to an int. You have defined `code` in your `vaccine` struct as a `char`, but, the `code` that you are comparing it to is an `int`.

Comment: If you use a `char` for both, you will need to use something like `strcmp()` for the `if` statement. If you use an `int` for both, you can compare with the `==` as you are now.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock what is the correct syntax for char? i tried "if(v.code == v.code)" , it gives me the whole record instead :v. but i think it was pointer.

Comment: If you want to compare chars, use: `if (strcmp(v.code, v.code) == 0)`.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock i wrote it but it gives me the whole record too. while(fread(&v,sizeof(vaccine),1,fp))
 { 
        if (strcmp(v.code, v.code) == 0){
        found=1;
  printf("\n%s\t%s\t%d",
        v.vacname,v.code,v.quantity);
  }
    }. any mistake?

Comment: When is `strcmp(v.code, v.code)`  never `0`? That was J's typo: try `strcmp(v.code, code)`. Aside, remove the `&` from `scanf("%s", &code);` if `code` is now an array.

Comment: True, but I thought the comparison might just be for trouble-shooting issues. I'm a little rusty on C, since it is in a struct, perhaps El needs `if (strcmp(&v.code, &v.code) == 0)`?

Comment: @Jeshua Lacock the point is, it's like writing `if(1 == 1)` comparing it with itself is always a match.

Comment: I know that. But it still isn't working for him so something else going on.

Comment: Of course it's not woking - *every record will be a match* because of your typo comparing `v.code` with `v.code`, instead of `code` with `v.code`.

Comment: i tried. nothing works haha

Comment: @WeatherVane I explained in the beginning that they both need to be either a string or an int. After explaining that, @El vhie used `v.code == v.code`, and I just used his   example because they are the same type.

Comment: I would try using a type that you know exists for testing. Like: `if (strcmp(v.code, 'foo') == 0)`. I would also add a `break` statement after the print record line.

Comment: Better would be `"foo"`

Comment: True - like I said I'm rusty with C. But yes, use `'` for a char and `"` for a str you are correct.

Comment: ah i ve solved it haha. this... while(fread(&v,sizeof(vaccine),1,fp)) 
    { 
        if (strcmp(v.code, &code) == 0)
        {
            printf("\n%s\t%s\t%d", 
            v.vacname,v.code,v.quantity); 
        } 
    }. thank u everyone <3 ))))